# custom header names with SoftArtisans OfficeWriter?

Tags: c#, excel

I am using SoftArtisans OfficeWriter tool to create an excel file.
By Using DataImportProperties.UseColumnNames=true the column headers are populated with the class property names but I want to give custom column headers.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Donot use DataImportProperties.UseColumnNames=true.Instead use cell specific formatting since it is header so for every cell row/column number is known.ex.     

    Style headerStyle = wb.CreateStyle();
                headerStyle.Font.Size = 10;
                headerStyle.Font.Bold = true;            
                ws.Cells[1, 0].Value = "Name";
                ws.Cells[1, 0].ApplyStyle(headerStyle);

You can also merge and group columns  as :
            ws[0, 0].Value = "Information";
            Palette pal = wb.Palette;
            Color group1Color = pal.GetClosestColor(255, 244, 205);
            headerStyle.BackgroundColor = group1Color;
            headerStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            ws[0, 0].ApplyStyle(headerStyle);
            ws.CreateArea(0, 0, 1, 13).MergeCells();
            ws.GroupColumns(0, 12, true);
//True/false keeps the group collapsed/uncollpasedwhen user opens the workbook.
```